# poner fecha en el programa con base de datos

Tags: data

buenas una preguntica es que estoy programando y quiero poner la fecha y que me la guarde el base de datos. en la columna de la tabla pongo date pero me arroja solo ceros.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código que estas usando para guardar esos datos, si no muy probablemente te cerraran la pregunta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con: ALTER TABLE productos CHANGE fecha_entrega fecha_entrega date DEFAULT '2022-01-14'; --> esto pondra la misma fecha en todos tus registros.

La fecha se captura con PHP o con JavaScript y la insertas en tu consulta, te dejo la documentacion de la funcion date() de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Por ejemplo para Bogota, Colombia

```
//Set the default time zone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$fechaActual = date("y-m-d");
$HoraActual = date("G:i:s", time());
```